# Android Fragment UI elements disappear when changing fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an android app that has multiple fragments, one for each feature. I'm currently using a drawer to access each feature, and in one particular feature I'm using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to [switch between fragments within that fragment](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter). When I create first open the app to access my fragment, the UI elements defined in my `layout.xml` file loads as expected. However, when I use my drawer to switch to a different fragment, and return to my original fragment, the original UI elements disappear.

**Drawer switching code in Base Activity to access different feature fragments**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ValueEventListener {
    FragmentManager fm;
    ArrayList<String> listOfAvailableRooms=new ArrayList<>();
    String timing="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // start of own code
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.f_map) {
            fragment = new MapFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.f_booking) {
            fragment = new CalendarFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.f_roomSearch) {
            fragment = new RoomSearchFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.f_authentication) {
            fragment = new AuthenticationFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragment = new MapFragment().newInstance(3, new LatLng(-53.965623629921105, -5.974991060793399));
        } else {
            fragment = new MapFragment();
        }

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) return new MapFragment();
            return new MapFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Client";
                case 1:
                    return "Server";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Overall Fragment for Feature**

```
public class AuthenticationFragment extends Fragment {
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public AuthenticationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static AuthenticationFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AuthenticationFragment fragment = new AuthenticationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authentication, container, false);
        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            switch (position){
                case 0: //CurrentBookings Fragment
                    return CurrentBookings.getInstance("Current");
                case 1: //UpcomingBookings Fragment
                    return UpcomingBookings.newInstance("Upcoming");
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            switch (position){
                case 0: //CurrentBookings Fragment
                    return "Current";
                case 1: //UpcomingBookings Fragment
                    return "Upcoming";
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Fragment with Disappearing UI elements**

```
public class CurrentBookings extends Fragment {
    private Button myButton;

    // newInstance constructer for creating fragment with arguments
    public static CurrentBookings newInstance(String title){
        CurrentBookings currentBookings = new CurrentBookings();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title",title);
        currentBookings.setArguments(args);
        return currentBookings;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        title = getArguments().getString("title");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_bookings,container,false);

        myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of App when first open fragment**
[image: screenshot first open fragment]

**Screenshot of App when revisiting fragment**
[image]
[image]

The UI element only appears again when the phone orientation changes. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where's the drawer switching code. Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You need to remove your child fragments of AuthenticationFragment manually.

When you set the adapter that time you have to add the both fragments in arraylist in your parentFragment so you can get full list of fragment so that you can easily remove the fragments on parent fragment's onDestroyView().

```
private class AuthenticationFragment extends Fragment{

private Arraylist fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();


private void setAdapter(){
    fragmentList.add(new FirstFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new SecondFragment());
............. code of adapter


}



    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Because you have used FragmentPagerAdapter in AuthenticationFragment.

Comment: Can I clarify if this is to be added in the Base Activity code (with the drawer) or in the AuthenticationFragment code?

Comment: I have updated my code. You should add the fragments in ArrayList and using that arraylist you should setAdapter so you can remove the fragment easily otherwise you will get NullPointerException. in remove method